# Fail to give reference to another JSON schema

Tags: node.js, json, express, jsonschema

I am new in JSON schema and trying to validate my request with JSON schema. So i created schema. But i don't know why i am not able to give refrence to any another schema which located in same folder can any one help me to how to give $ref

```
{
    "$id":"file:/schemas/ActionType",
    "title":"ActionType",
    "type":"object",
    "properties":{
        "ActionType":{
            "enum":["fullLoad","update","insert","delete"]
        }

    },
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "required": ["ActionType"]
}
```

```
{
    "$id":"file:/schemas/ERoaming",
    "title":"ERoaming",
    "type":"object",
    "properties":{
        "ActionType":{
            "type":"object",
            "$ref":"/schemas/ActionType.json"
        }
    },
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "required": ["ActionType"],
    "$defs": {
        
      }
}
```

I tried with without $id, relative path, path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I don't think that's a valid file URI. It should look like `file:///path/to/schemas/ActionType` with three `/`s after the `:` and the full system path. You can't use a relative path.

Otherwise, everything looks fine with the schema. Another likely problem is that not all JSON Schema libraries understand files that reference the file system. You'll want to make sure the one you're using supports that feature.

When you're working with schemas in files, it's unnecessary to use `$id`. If the library properly handles file system references, the full path and filename should be automatically be used as the schema identifier. Then you can use relative references like I'm sure you're familiar with, `{ "$ref": "./ActionType.json" }`.